# hosting competition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a complicated, multi-layered product/process that needs to be developed in SQL et al.  I am considering hosting a competition with a significant prize or series of prizes.  I am not connected to the industry whatsoever.  How would I go about it and downfalls...or is it even doable?  Are there organizations that host competitions etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question is incredibly subjective, and opinion-based questions are considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow. Please refer to the StackOverflow help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the documentation for topics that are considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)'. As for your last point, there are several. Googling will reveal sites like HackerRank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codechef, HackerRank, HackerEarth, all of these host competitions on demand. Search for more info about them online

Comment: I must have been using the wrong search terms... did not find those.  On it.  Thanks.   perfect